# coldfusion xmlsearch find multiple nodes

Tags: xml, coldfusion, menu, coldbox

I have an extensive menu in which I would like to search for and manipulate menu items quickly.  Is it possible to search for a list of ids, lets say something along the lines of

```
list contains ("0,57,19,22,30,31,32,33,34,36,45,53,63,58,59,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,46,47,48,50,51,52,54,55,16", "45")
```

example node:

```
<li class="standby" id="id61">
```

as of right now I am using a loop in cfscript

```
        if(listLen(IdsToRemove.List,",") GT 1){
            for(i=1;i lte listLen(IdsToRemove.List);i=i+1) {
                valueToFind="li[@id='" & listGetAt(IdsToRemove.List,i) & "']";
                findNode=XmlSearch(MyNavigation.myMenu,"//" & valueToFind);
                Instance.UDFLibrary.XmlDeleteNodes(XmlDocument=MyNavigation.myMenu,Nodes=findNode);
            }
        }
```

I am really hoping to search for a list and delete all the nodes at once.  thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contains()` in xpath expressions to search through a string. If you treat that string as a list you can skip the outer loop.

```
var ids = ListChangeDelims(IdsToRemove.List, ',', ' '); // commas to spaces
var nodes = XmlSearch(MyNavigation.myMenu,"//li[contains(' " & ids & " ', concat(' ', substring(@id,3), ' '))]");
```

ids would be something like " 0 57 19 " and `concat(' ', substring(@id,3), ' ')` would be something like " 0 " so the expression above is essentially a long-winded version of ListFind() using all but the first 2 characters of the nodes id.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I made some edits to complete your box and check off this question as good to go

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full setup I am using in case others need help with this:

```
<cfscript>
    testme=structnew();
    testme.menu=xmlNav(buildNav(qgetNav));
    testme.menustring=tostring(xmlNav(buildNav(qgetNav)));

    testme.valueToFind="li[@id='id56']";
    testme.findNode=XmlSearch(testme.menu,"//" & testme.valueToFind);

    testme.List="0 16 41 42 43 16 41 42 43 16 41 42 43 16 41 42 43 ";
    testme.ids = ListChangeDelims(testme.List,' ',','); // commas to spaces
    testme.nodes = XmlSearch(testme.menu,"//li[contains(' " & testme.ids & " ', concat(' ', substring(@id,3), ' '))]");

    XmlDeleteNodes(XmlDocument=testme.menu,Nodes=testme.nodes);

</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#testme#">

<cffunction name="buildNav" returntype="array">
    <cfargument name="qGetNav" type="query">
    <cfset var sLU = structNew()>
    <cfset var aMenu = arrayNew(1)>
    <cfset var aNavMenuItems = arrayNew(1)>
    <cfset var sThis = structNew()>
    <cfloop query="qGetNav">
        <cfset sThis = structNew()>
        <cfset sThis.route = qGetNav.Route>
        <cfset sthis.textDesc = qGetNav.textDesc>
        <cfset sthis.linkTitle = qGetNav.linkTitle>
        <cfset sthis.linkTarget = qGetNav.linkTarget>
        <cfset sthis.Version = qGetNav.version>
        <cfif sthis.Version Eq "CB">
            <cfset arrayAppend(aNavMenuItems,sThis.route)>
        </cfif> 
        <cfset sthis.navID = qGetNav.navID> 
        <cfset sthis.aChildren = arrayNew(1)>
        <cfset sLU[qGetNav.navID]  = sThis>
        <cfif val(qGetNav.navParentID) NEQ 0>
            <cfset arrayAppend(sLU[qGetNav.navParentID].aChildren, sThis)>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset arrayAppend(aMenu, sThis)>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn aMenu>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="xmlNav" returntype="xml">
    <cfargument name="aNav" type="array">
    <cfset var navXML="">
    <cfxml variable="navXML">
        <cfoutput>
            #xmlNavList(aNav=arguments.aNav)#
        </cfoutput>
    </cfxml>
    <cfreturn navXML>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="xmlNavList" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="aNav" type="array">
    <cfargument name="level" type="numeric" default="0">
    <cfset var iNav = "">
    <ul 
        <cfif arguments.level GT 0>
            class="sub-nav-main-links nestingLevel<cfoutput>#arguments.level#</cfoutput>"
        <cfelse>
            id="nav-main-links"
        </cfif> 
        >
        <cfloop array="#aNav#" index="iNav">
            <cfoutput>
                <cfif iNav.Version Eq "CB">
                    <cfset iNav.Route="/?event=" & iNav.Route>
                <cfelseif iNav.Version Eq "L">
                    <cfset iNav.Route="http://legacy" & iNav.Route>
                </cfif> 
                <li class="standby" id="id#iNav.navid#">
                    <a href="#iNav.route#" title="#iNav.linkTitle#" target="#iNav.linkTarget#">
                        #iNav.textDesc# <font class="menuItemType">(#iNav.Version#)</font>
                    </a>
                    <cfif arrayLen(iNav.aChildren) GT 0>
                        <cfset xmlNavList(iNav.aChildren,arguments.level+1)>
                    </cfif>
                </li>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
    </ul>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="xmlGetNodePath" access="public" returntype="string"output="false" hint="I take a given XML node and return it's full XML path.">
    <cfargument name="node" type="any" required="true" hint="I am the XML node who's location is being reverse engineered."/>
    <cfset var local={ } />
    <cfset local.fullPath="" />
    <cfset local.marker="udf:xmlGetNodePath" />
    <cfset local.node=arguments.node />
    <cfloop condition="true">
        <cfif ( !structKeyExists( local.node, "xmlParent" ) || !structKeyExists(local.node.xmlParent, "xmlName" ) )>
            <cfbreak />
        </cfif>
        <cfset local.node.xmlAttributes[ local.marker ]=true />
        <cfset local.siblings=xmlSearch( local.node.xmlParent, ( "./" & local.node.xmlName)) />
        <cfloop index="local.siblingIndex" from="1" to="#arrayLen( local.siblings )#"step="1">
            <cfif structKeyExists( local.siblings[ local.siblingIndex ].xmlAttributes,local.marker )>
                <cfset local.fullPath=( "/" & local.node.xmlName & "[" & local.siblingIndex& "]" & local.fullPath ) />
                <cfbreak />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset structDelete( local.node.xmlAttributes, local.marker ) />
        <cfset local.node=local.node.xmlParent />
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn local.fullPath />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="XmlDeleteNodes" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="I remove a node or an array of nodes from the given XML document.">
    <!--- Define arugments. --->
    <cfargument name="XmlDocument" type="any" required="true" hint="I am a ColdFusion XML document object."/>
    <cfargument name="Nodes" type="any" required="false" hint="I am the node or an array of nodes being removed from the given document." />
    <!--- Define the local scope. --->
    <cfset var LOCAL=StructNew() />
    <!---Check to see if we have a node or array of nodes. If weonly have
    one node passed in, let's create an array ofit so we can assume an array
    going forward.--->
    <cfif NOT IsArray( ARGUMENTS.Nodes )>
        <!--- Get a reference to the single node. --->
        <cfset LOCAL.Node=ARGUMENTS.Nodes />
        <!--- Convert single node to array. --->
        <cfset ARGUMENTS.Nodes=[ LOCAL.Node ] />
    </cfif>
    <!---Flag nodes for deletion. We are going to need to deletethese via
    the XmlChildren array of the parent, so weneed to be able to differentiate
    them from siblings.Also, we only want to work with actual ELEMENT nodes,not
    attributes or anything, so let's remove any nodesthat are not element nodes.--->
    <cfloop index="LOCAL.NodeIndex" from="#ArrayLen( ARGUMENTS.Nodes )#" to="1" step="-1">
        <!--- Get a node short-hand. --->
        <cfset LOCAL.Node=ARGUMENTS.Nodes[ LOCAL.NodeIndex ] />
        <!---Check to make sure that this node has an XmlChildrenelement. If it
        does, then it is an element node. Ifnot, then we want to get rid of it.--->
        <cfif StructKeyExists( LOCAL.Node, "XmlChildren" )>
          <!--- Set delet flag. --->
          <cfset LOCAL.Node.XmlAttributes[ "delete-me-flag" ]="true" />
        <cfelse>
          <!---This is not an element node. Delete it from outlist of nodes to delete.--->
          <cfset ArrayDeleteAt(ARGUMENTS.Nodes,LOCAL.NodeIndex) />
        </cfif>
     </cfloop>
    <!---Now that we have flagged the nodes that need to bedeleted, we can
    loop over them to find their parents.All nodes should have a parent, except
    for the rootnode, which we cannot delete.--->
    <cfloop index="LOCAL.Node" array="#ARGUMENTS.Nodes#">
      <!--- Get the parent node. --->
      <cfset LOCAL.ParentNodes=XmlSearch( LOCAL.Node, "../" ) />
      <!---Check to see if we have a parent node. We can'tdelete the root node,
      and we also be deleting otherelements as well - make sure it is all playingnicely
      together. As a final check, make sure thatout parent has children (only
      happens if we aredealing with the root document element).--->
      <cfif (ArrayLen( LOCAL.ParentNodes ) AND StructKeyExists( LOCAL.ParentNodes[1], "XmlChildren" ))>
            <!--- Get the parent node short-hand. --->
            <cfset LOCAL.ParentNode=LOCAL.ParentNodes[ 1 ] />
            <!---Now that we have a parent node, we want to loopover it's children
            to one the nodes flagged asdeleted (and delete them). As we do this, wewant
            to loop over the children backwards so thatwe don't go out of bounds as
            we start to removechild nodes.--->
            <cfloop index="LOCAL.NodeIndex" from="#ArrayLen( LOCAL.ParentNode.XmlChildren )#"to="1" step="-1">
                <!--- Get the current node shorthand. --->
                <cfset LOCAL.Node=LOCAL.ParentNode.XmlChildren[ LOCAL.NodeIndex ] />
                <!---Check to see if this node has been flaggedfor deletion.--->
                <cfif StructKeyExists( LOCAL.Node.XmlAttributes, "delete-me-flag" )>
                        <!--- Delete this node from parent. --->
                        <cfset ArrayDeleteAt(LOCAL.ParentNode.XmlChildren,LOCAL.NodeIndex) />
                        <!---Clean up the node by removing thedeletion flag. This node might still
                        beused by another part of the program.--->
                        <cfset StructDelete(LOCAL.Node.XmlAttributes, "delete-me-flag") />
                    </cfif>
            </cfloop>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Wow, that's kinda rude chris. You solved the problem using my answer, marked my answer as correct, then posted a wall of code that's largely irrelevant to the question you asked (except for the part that uses my answer) and gave yourself the credit for the correct answer.

Comment: I thought we were supposed to mark what we finally used at completion.  my mistake, no worries, I tossed it back.  I just wanted others to see the full solution.  I tried to edit your post but you never accepted the edits as I requested.  can we merge these together? seems like that would make more sense for everyone searching for this.

Comment: Thanks for putting that right. I spent quite a lot of time on my answer. My complaint had to do with your question being about "finding multiple nodes" and "searching through a list", not about the implementation of XmlDeleteNodes (since it seems you already had that). Adding the XmlDeleteNodes code in full may be helpful to others but it's not really an answer to the question you asked.

Comment: No problem, hope you have a great week.